# 2-D inverse Fourier transform of Heaviside function

Tags: integration, fourier-transform, bessel-functions, step-function

Now I have a Heaviside function $H(K-\sqrt{k^2+l^2})$ in a 2D $\hat k$ space, where $k$ and $l$ are two variables in that space. In a paper, it is said that the inverse Fourier transform of this Heaviside function is:
$$
\frac{K}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} J_1(K\sqrt{x^2+y^2})
$$
where $x$ and $y$ are variables in 2D real space and $J_1$ is the first order Bessel function.

How to derive this result?

**Attempts:**

I try to perform this transform by:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} d k \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} d l \
H(K-\sqrt{k^2+l^2}) e^{i2\pi(kx+ly)}
$$
Using the properity of Heaviside function, the integral becomes:
$$
\iint_{k^2+l^2 \leq K^2} dk \ dl \
e^{i2\pi(kx+ly)}
$$
Switch to polar coordinates(set $k=r\cos\theta$ and $l=r\sin\theta$):
$$
\int_0^{K} dr \int_0^{2\pi} d\theta \
r e^{i2\pi r(x\cos\theta+y\sin\theta)}
$$
After integral over $r$, we have:
$$
\int_0^{2\pi} d\theta \
\frac{-1+[1-i2\pi K(x\cos\theta+y\sin\theta)]e^{i2\pi K(x\cos\theta+y\sin\theta)}}
{4\pi^2(x\cos\theta+y\sin\theta)^2}
$$
I don't know how to deal with this integral and how to transform it into Bessel function.

Comment: SiThere's an analogous problem in optics; far-field diffraction just gives the Fourier transform (as does a lens to a focal plane). The diffraction pattern from a circular aperture (often called the [Airy disk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airy_disk)) and as $J1(x)/x$ (where $x$ is some radial variable) it's seems very similar. Perhaps a nice book of optics will have the derivation and you can adapt it to your variables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's take as our starting point the integral
$$
I:=\int_0^{K} dr \int_0^{2\pi} d\theta\, r e^{i2\pi r(x\cos\theta+y\sin\theta)}.
\tag{1}
$$
With $(x,y)=(\rho\cos\phi,\rho\sin\phi)$, we may compute the angular integral with
the help of the [Jacobi-Anger expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Properties):
\begin{align}
\int_0^{2\pi} d\theta\,e^{i2\pi r\rho\cos(\theta-\phi)}&=
\int_{0}^{2\pi} d\theta\,\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}i^nJ_n(2\pi r\rho)e^{in(\theta-\phi)} \\
&=2\pi J_0(2\pi r\rho). \tag{2}
\end{align}
Now, to compute the radial integral, we use the [identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Recurrence_relations) $\frac{d}{dx}(xJ_1(x))=xJ_0(x)$:
\begin{align}
\int_0^K2\pi J_0(2\pi r\rho)r\,dr&=\frac{1}{2\pi\rho^2}\int_0^{2\pi K\rho}\xi J_0(\xi)\,d\xi \\
&=\frac{K}{\rho}J_1(2\pi K\rho) \\
&=\frac{K}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} J_1\left(2\pi K\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right). \tag{3}
\end{align}
(The factor of $2\pi$ in the argument of $J_1$ probably has to do with the convention used in the definition of the [Fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Tables_of_important_Fourier_transforms).)